# Android Twitter integration not working on different OS version

Tags: android, twitter, android-asynctask, twitter4j, networkonmainthread

I am trying to integrate twiiter with my android app and I am facing some OS compatibility problem. When I am running my app in 2.3.4 android device its working properly, but when I am running same program on my 4.1.2 android jelly bean device its giving me an error due to doing background work on main thread. But I can't figure out how to do this job in background thread using async task.

My current implementation is as below

TwitterActivity.java

```
final Runnable mUpdateTwitterNotification = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tweet sent !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(
                TwitterActivity.this));
        setContentView(R.layout.twitter_main);
        this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        message = extras.getString("message");

        tvLoginStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status);
        edtTweetMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tweet_msg);
        btnTweet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tweet);
        btnClearCredentials = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_clear_credentials);
        tvHeader = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_text);
        tvHeader.setText("Tweeter");

        edtTweetMsg.setText(message);

        btnTweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = edtTweetMsg.getText().toString();

                if (!message.equals("")) {
                    if (message.length() <= 140) {

                        if (TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)) {
                            sendTweet();
                        } else {
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    TwitterPrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("tweet_msg", message);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(TwitterActivity.this,
                                "Maximum 140 charecter allowed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(TwitterActivity.this,
                            "Nothing to be post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnClearCredentials.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearCredentials();
                updateLoginStatus();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateLoginStatus();
    }

    public void updateLoginStatus() {   <-----------Location of error 
        tvLoginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : "
                + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
    }

    public void sendTweet() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs, edtTweetMsg.getText()
                            .toString());
                    mTwitterHandler.post(mUpdateTwitterNotification);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        t.start();
    }

    private void clearCredentials() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN);
        edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
        edit.commit();
    }
```

It showing error on my method updateLogin()

TwitterUtil.java

```
public class TwitterUtils {

    public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

        String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterConstants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                TwitterConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

        try {
            twitter.getAccountSettings();
            return true;
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void sendTweet(SharedPreferences prefs, String msg)
            throws Exception {
        String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

        AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TwitterConstants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                TwitterConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        twitter.updateStatus(msg);
    }
}
```

I am using following jar files for this app

```
signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
twitter4j-core-3.0.1.jar
httpclient-4.0.1.jar
```

My error stacktrace is as below

```
 Stack:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.appovative.poi/com.appovative.places.TwitterActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:34)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:156)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:89)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1690)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getAccountSettings(TwitterImpl.java:556)
    at com.appovative.places.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(TwitterUtils.java:24)
    at com.appovative.places.TwitterActivity.updateLoginStatus(TwitterActivity.java:112)
    at com.appovative.places.TwitterActivity.onResume(TwitterActivity.java:107)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2573)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following code:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateLoginStatus();
}

public void updateLoginStatus() {   <-----------Location of error 
    tvLoginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : "
            + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
}
```

with this:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    new loginToTwitterTask().execute();
}

    private class loginToTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private ProgressDialog pdLoading;

    private boolean isAuthenticated;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(TwitterActivity.this);
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        isAuthenticated = TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        tvLoginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : "
                +isAuthenticated);
    }
}
```

**Reference:**
[AsyncTask in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: thnx, right now I am facing another problem in my onClick() method.Please look at my onClick() method .There also I am using
if(TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)) which showing error now

Comment: @DKBHOI: you should have a `boolean` variable `isAuthenticated`in your `TwitterActivity.java` which can store the authentication status after calling `loginToTwitterTask` from `onResume` . so that you can use it afterwards instead of calling `TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)` afterwards.

Comment: @DKBHOI: I'm glad to help.by the way,its Joisar

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the update status inside a runnable thread.
Ex:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     try {
          twitter.updateStatus(message);
     } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }}).start();
```

You can also refer to this [tutorial-on-uploading-image-on-twitter-using-twitter4j.](http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/tutorial-on-uploading-image-on-twitter-using-twitter4j/)